# Extract SMTP address from Exchange User in the FROM field of a message

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to organize messages in folders by domain (and possibly user). I have a script but it can't get the SMTP addresses from exchange users. The below code is an excerpt from the address extractor.

```
///For each obj in objFolder.Items
    If obj.SenderEmailAddress = "EX" Then
    Set objSender = obj.Sender
        If Not (objSender Is Nothing) Then
            Set objExchUser = Sender.GetExchangeUser()
            If Not (objExchUser Is Nothing) Then
                strSender = objExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If obj.SenderEmailAddress = "" Then
        strSender = "ERROR@ERROR.GOV"
        Else
        MsgBox obj.SenderEmailAddress
        'MsgBox obj.PrimarySmtpAddress 'errs out
        'MsgBox Sender.GetExchangeUser() 'errs out
        'MsgBox Obj.Sender.GetExchangeUser() 'errs out
        strSender = obj.PrimarySmtpAddress
        End If
    End If
///Next
```

The code works but for those coming from an email group (helpdesk@myexchange.org for example) or spoofed email addresses.

obj.SenderEmailAddress results in "/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (removedtextforstack)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=7E2removedtextforstackF6-USERNAME"

I believe this is to be expected, but Sender.GetExchangeUser() gives an Object Required error. I don't particularly want 3000 lines of code to dig through AD to try to look up an AD code/user for every email. We use office 365 and it's managed by many people, so things aren't straitforward with accessing the address lists.

Comment: Hah!  Yes I see your meaning now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MailItem.Sender.GetExchnageUser().ProimarySmtpAddress` should work fine for the EX senders, but your code checks the `SenderEmailAddress` property instead of `SenderEmailType`. Change it to

```
If obj.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
```

You can also check the PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_SMTP_ADDRESS property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D02001F`, use `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`) before using the `MailItem.Sender` property (which is more expensive)

Comment: Yeah, that SenderEmailAddress property fixed a LOT of problems. I cant believe I missed that! Thanks! I plan to implement the PR_SENT... soon too. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have a work-around that seems decently efficient.

```
Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"

a = Split(obj.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS), vbCrLf)
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    If InStr(1, a(i), "From:", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
    MsgBox Replace(Split(a(i), "<")(1), ">", "")
    End If
Next
```

This pulls the SMTP address directly from the header and does not care what type of message it is.

There still has to be a better way though...