# Extract SMTP address from Outlook Nickname

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to display a message when sending to an external address. I used various stack overflow questions to create the VBA below. I use Office 365.

I found that a recipient which Outlook has assigned as an Outlook nickname does not resolve with an SMTP address.

Instead, the `Recipients.Item(i).Address` attribute resolves to something like

> /o=NT5/ou=00000000000000000000000000000000/cn=122E0E7203FE4F448EC35B53EE8523A4

from which I am unable to extract the SMTP address. I need to check if this recipient is an external recipient.

I tried using the Recipients.Item(i).Name attribute (which just includes the first part of the address before the @) and attempted to resolve this using `Session.CreateRecipient`, but this fails. I also tried the same with the `Recipients.Item(i).Address` attribute.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xRecipients As Outlook.Recipients
Dim i As Long
Dim xRecipientAddress As String
Dim xExternal As Integer

On Error Resume Next

xExternal = 0

If Item.Class <> olMail Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set xMailItem = Item
Set xRecipients = xMailItem.Recipients

For i = xRecipients.Count To 1 Step -1
    xRecipientAddress = xRecipients.Item(i).Address
   
    If Left(xRecipientAddress, 1) <> "/" Then
    'external address
        If InStrRev(LCase(xRecipientAddress), "@email.domain") = 0 Then
            'Any other SMTP Email domain
            xExternal = 1
        End If
    Else
    
        'catch for outlook nickname cache
        If Left(xRecipientAddress, 6) = "/o=NT5" Then
 
            'Code to get SMTP address from outlook nickname   
    
        End If

    End If

Next
```

Note the @email.domain is updated in my code to our SMTP domain name

The code should assign xExternal = 1 if any external recipients are found in the recipients list. This should include any recipients Outlook has created an Outlook Nickname for and those with just SMTP addresses.

Comment: Consider not using `On Error Resume Next` until you know why following closely with `On Error GoTo 0` is "mandatory".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract SMTP address from Exchange User in the FROM field of a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527771/extract-smtp-address-from-exchange-user-in-the-from-field-of-a-message)

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

```
If Left(xRecipientAddress, 6) = "/o=NT5" Then

  Debug.Print xRecipients.Item(i).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress

End If
```

Also, i don't think `/0=NT5` will be consistent, so might want to change that.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. That didn't seem to work - I just get a blank response - the AddressEntry attribute returns the first part of the address before the @, but the PrimarySMTPAddress attribute is blank.

Comment: Ohh ... I am not able to replicate your issue. Otherwise would have helped more. :)